# Using BLOB in where clause in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am working on an application that will need to do some verification on data by checking fingerprints stored in a MySQL database.It was proposed to use proprietary software such as 'AFIS'..but i am wondering if the check can be done by using the BLOB column in the "where" clause of a select statement to filter the data. Is this possible?

The code i have in mind is something like this:

```
     Select id from mytable
     where image not in
    (select image from other table)
```

With the image columns being of blob datatype

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(your_blob_field) > 0
```

char_length() works on a blob column type... if that is anything but 0 then you know you've got something in there.

Comment: Thanks Sudhir..what i mean is something like this "select id from mytable where image not in (select image from othertable)...with the image column being of blob datatype.

Comment: @Sayem Ahmed...his answer concerned checking if there is content in the column..i want to check if the columns have the "same" image. Thanks.