# BLOB type parameter in where clause of sequelize

Tags: mysql, geometry, blob, sequelize.js, sqldatatypes

I have an attribute of a model which is of type [GEOMETRY](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/datatypes/#geometry)('*polygon*') in sequelize with database mySQL.

The attribute of this type is getting saved in DB as of BLOB type.

I want to perform sequelize implicit findOne operation on this model specifying this geometry type attribute in the where clause.

When I am trying to do the same, its giving me an error without any error statement whereas, it gives the result if I specify any other field of the table in the where clause.

My code sample is as :

> User model :

```
module.exports = {

    attributes: {
        geometry: {
            type: Sequelize.GEOMETRY('POLYGON')
        }
    }
}
```

> User Controller :

```
find: function(req, res) {

        var point = {
            type: 'Polygon',
            coordinates: [
                [
                    [100.0, 0.0],
                    [101.0, 0.0],
                    [101.0, 1.0],
                    [100.0, 1.0],
                    [100.0, 0.0]
                ]
            ]
        };

        User.findOne({
            where: {
              "geometry": point
            }
        }).then(function(polygonData) {
            return res.ok(polygonData);
        }).catch(function(exception) {
            return res.badRequest(exception);
        });

    }
```

When i am trying to retrieve the same, its giving me error object as :

```
{
  "error@context":{
                      }
}
```

I have referred to few of these already existing questions :

[Mysql query check the blob column type in where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28903599/mysql-query-check-the-blob-column-type-in-where-clause)

[Using BLOB in where clause in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9782280/using-blob-in-where-clause-in-mysql)

but still in vain.

If someone can help me on this, as of how I can specify blob type in where clause, it will be great.
I would not prefer doing it through raw query, but if no other way then anyways have to.

In need of more info, one can refer [here](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/master/test/integration/model/geometry.test.js).

Comment: <rant>Yet another case of 3rd party software getting in the way of using MySQL?</rant>